# Как обновить json-поле с данными из подзапроса?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `table1` с json-колонкой `data`

SELECT id,data FROM table1;

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5'} |

Я могу использовать:

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`t1`.`data`, JSON_OBJECT('key1', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2'));
```

И получу:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} |

Но как я могу обновить данные из подзапроса, используя JSON_MERGE_PATCH? Например, из `table2`:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'key10' | 'value10' |
| 2 | 'key13' | 'value13' |

Я пробовал "SELECT key, value FROM table2" с JSON_ARRAY и т.д. в JSON_MERGE_PATCH, но не нашёл корректного варианта.

Ожидаемый результат:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3', 'key10': 'value10', 'key13': 'value13'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5', 'key10': 'value10', 'key13': 'value13'} |

Comment: что в итоге то должно получиться?

Comment: Добавил выше в пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`t1`.`data`, 
    (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(`key`, value) FROM table2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table1 
JOIN table2 USING (id)
SET table1.data = JSON_MERGE_PATCH(table1.data, JSON_OBJECT(table2.`key`, table2.value));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6c9224a1b0258d4423cbc099c3bffe8

---

> Но это же добавит только по одному значению. А нужно добавить все пары значений из table2. В table2 может быть и больше записей. – WD_KMS

Значит, вместо table2 пишете подзапрос, который объединяет все записи таблицы в один JSON, и используете CROSS JOIN.

```sql
UPDATE table1 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(table2.`key`, table2.value) data
             FROM table2 ) table3
SET table1.data = JSON_MERGE_PATCH(table1.data, table3.data);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6253c49766897a272c154ab1f91227c

Comment: Но это же добавит только по одному значению. А нужно добавить все пары значений из table2. В table2 может быть и больше записей.

Comment: @WD_KMS Ну очевидное же решение... Добавил.